# Significado desta sintaxe

Tags: c++, sintaxe

Preciso continuar um trabalho que está parcialmente pronto. No entanto não encontrei na internet arquivos que descrevessem ou ensinassem isso de uma forma compreensível. Qual o significado desta sintaxe ?
 Ide: NetBeans e linguagem C++

```
void Grafo::buscarElosEmProfundidade(No *origem, std::function<bool(No*, No*, Elo*)> func)
```

A parte No origem eu entendo que seja um ponteiro, mas e essa parte de std::functio bool(No *, No *, Elo *) func)? o que isso significa ?

A função completa é esta :

```
void Grafo::buscarElosEmProfundidade(No *origem, std::function<bool(No*, No*, Elo*)> func){
ListaParEloPercorrido *percorridos = this->getPercorridos(false);
ListaParNoVisitado *visitados = this->getVisitados(false);
if(!origem->getElos()->empty())
this->buscarElosEmProfundidadeAux(*(origem->getElos()->begin()), origem, visitados, percorridos, func);
delete percorridos;
delete visitados;
```

}
 Eu tentei chamar esta função assim : buscarElosEmProfundidade(No*ponteiro) e deu erro .
Qual a forma certa de chamá-la então ?

E ela não deveria ser void, certo ? Pois a intenção desta função é retornar uma lista com os nós que são "atingíveis" a partir da origem.

Comment: Se você que está fazendo o código não sabe, pra gente fica mais complicado ainda. S sintaxe é sobre isto: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function Agora como usar depende do seu código. Você não postou informações que indiquem como deve ser usado.

Answer (score 0):

Esta notação `std::function<bool(No*, No*, Elo*)>func` indica um ponteiro para uma função de protótipo `bool func(No*, No*, Elo*)` que deve ser passada como parâmetro na chamada da função `buscarElosEmProfundidade`.

Você deve fazer mais ou menos assim:

```
// ...
// ...
// ...

// coloquei nomes genéricos na função e nos parâmetros porque não
// sei como serão usados, mas você deve colocar nomes explicativos
bool nomeFunc(No* no1, No* no2, Elo* elo)
{
   // ...
   // sua implementação
   // ...
}

// ...
// ...
// ...

No origem;

// ...
// ...
// ...

buscarElosEmProfundidade(&origem, nomeFunc);

// ...
// ...
// ...
```

PS. código não testado.